# Git / VS 2022 / Check in running very slow on credential-manager-core

Tags: git, azure-devops, credentials, visual-studio-2022

We are using GIT with VS 2022 with our Azure Dev ops.

All of a sudden about a week ago, I am seeing this message when syncing with the remote server:

"Syncing - pulling the current branch -> credential-manager-core".

It will eventually finish, but this use to be very quick!

[image]

I think git credential manager core has to deal with this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50918842/16807881).

I've tried to reset this, by removing it and then VS 2022 has me log back into.

This doesn't seem to work.

This use to work fine. I updated to the latest VS 2022 and it still happens:

VS 2022 Version 17.1.2

I've also blew away my git repo from my local computer and then brought it back down.

Any other ideas?